# How do I convert multiple mp3 files to mp4 with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, mp3, mp4

The following command takes the mp3, attaches an image to it, and converts it to an mp4:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -loop 1 -i image.png -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -shortest output.mp4
```

I need to do this for all the mp3s in a folder.  How would I code this?

Comment: Hi Doc Chop, [welcome to Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). What are you trying to achieve? A video of each MP3 with a single image? Or a different image per MP3 file?

Comment: Which OS? Windows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: Thank you!  I'm trying to apply the same image to each mp3 in a folder.  The operating system is windows 8 and the desired output for the file is mp4.   I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Linux or some flavor of UNIX and `image.png` is literal:

```
cd /media/volume/mp3_directory

ls *.mp3 | while read mp3File ; do outputFile=$(basename "${mp3File}" .mp3) ; ffmpeg -i "${mp3File}" -loop 1 -i image.png -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -shortest "${outputFile}".mp4 ; done
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Can I get this code for windows please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to batch convert you should use the shell for it (assuming Linux).
Use find to return all files in a directory and '| xargs' to apply the given ffmpeg command to each.

Comment: Can you update your answer with a complete example?

Answer (score 0):

echo "rename the Source Mp3 File To audio.mp3"
echo "the Output Mp4 File Then Are video.mp4"

ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -acodec copy -r 1 -shortest -vf scale=640:480 video.mp4
rm audio.mp3

Above is THE code to Convert mp3 to mp4 with image.jpg as video image want THE script to Convert all mp3 in folder to mp4 and save ex. video01.mp4 video02.mp4 IF you understand me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).